# Google AdSense - High Payment

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I tried Google AdSense for the first time and surprisingly I got very high stats from the first day of using it.

- I got $2.53 for 40-50 visitors in one day and my RPM was $80.

I disabled the advertising and waited 1 month. Now I have received the finalized earnings and there were all $2.53 (100%) received.

- How this could be possible? How I could be paid so much?

Answer (score 1):

Your RPM is only so high because you have so little traffic.

Certain ads pay more then others so for example if you only have 1 ad impression and the viewer legitimately clicked on the ad and you were credited $2 for that single ad impression/click your RPM would show as $2000 but of course you wouldn't expect to actually make $2000 per 1000 views.

RPM is just the outcome of (Estimated earnings / Number of page views) * 1000 and with a sample size of only 40-50 views it isn't of much use. RPM is calculated with the values of earnings and number of page views, it doesn't determine what you will be paid for future impressions.